# Get Entries from Every Site

Tags: templating, entries, sites

How do I pull in entries from every site? I can't even seem to pass more than one argument to the `.siteId` parameter:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ 
    section: 'resources', 
    siteId: [1,2,3],
}).all %}
```

That gives me the error:

> Argument 2 passed to craft\services\Elements::getPlaceholderElement()
>   must be of the type integer, array given

I also tried:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({ 
    section: 'resources', 
    siteId: craft.app.sites.allSiteIds,
}).all %}
```

But got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per current conversation on Github, this isn’t possible. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2854

#### Update (2021)

Now supports arrays or `*` for all sites.

[Craft 3.x documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#siteid)